# Samsung S6 Edge Screen

Tags: factory-reset

I have a Galaxy s6 Edge and the screen functionas, however the touch screen facility no longer works. I am trying to clear the data prior to sending it off as it holds financial data.

I have tried the manual reset using the up/down and ... options but that just reboots the phone.

Is there anyway I can access the phone using my PC to either force a factory reset or wipe?

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: Is [usb-debugging](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-debugging/info) enabled on your device?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your S6 edge remotely on your computer by using [SideSync](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/convergence/sidesync/).

However, your phone will need WiFi to be turned *ON* or to be plugged into the computer using a USB cable to allow the connection. Hope this helps.